# SQL Server SQL executed history

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you please advise as we need to extract last 1 year of SQL executed in the server (1-year history SQL executed) with the SQL statement?

I have been using below version

- SQL Server Management Studio v15.0.18369.0
- SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) v16.100.46041.41

  SELECT *
  FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS t
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(t.sql_handle)
  ORDER BY t.last_execution_time desc

This query returns only 3000 rows and date of execution from 17th June

Can you please advise if there any other place to get the history or any other third party tool available to pull the SQL history for last 1 year

Thank you

Comment: dm_exec_query_stats is just *cache*, outdated entries are regularly removed, and memory pressure or reboot will clear the entire cache.

Comment: Thanks i do have backup of the database everyweek. will that help to check the SQL history

Comment: If you use full recovery, https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-log.aspx can help reading non-select queries

Comment: We are after the select query histroy of users executed.i have tried sqlcomplete but its pulling from cache as well .

Comment: select history is lost after the plan cache is cleared.

Comment: Restart the server also clear the plan cache.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237494/does-restarting-the-sql-services-on-the-machine-clear-the-server-cache-for-th

Comment: any other way to acc,omplish i have tried trc file as well cant see the user executed sql

Comment: Bottom Line: unless you were capturing and archiving, then No you can't do this, unless, you have all your TLogs and use a 3rd party tool, but you will no doubt be drinking from the firehose. The question is: why do you need this? I suspect you have an XY problem.

Comment: we have lost a drive which has all the sql written and its not possible to rewrite again hence we are looking an option to retrive from the history, thanks

Comment: Maybe time to fix those backups?......

Comment: SQL Server does not have this capacity, and asking us to recommend a tool that will do so is off-topic here according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: thanks all for your time guys, cheers

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to note about DMV.

1. The data in the DMVs are transient, as they are removed once the plan is removed from plan cache. So, you will not have all the queries in the DMV.
2. The backups don't contain DMV data, except for sys.db_db_index_phycial_stats. [Read more](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8d97194a-213d-4b2b-a0fc-db86f03d879c/backing-up-data-of-dynamic-management-views)

So, in your case, if you want to monitor your queries, you are having few options.

1. Set up extended events (even though it is not intrusive compared to sql profiler, due to the way you are setting it up, it can lead to performance issues as well)
2. use sp_whoisactive to regularly save the results to another table. But, due to the schedule of capture, there could be some statements missed in gap between schedules. [Read more on capture output](http://whoisactive.com/docs/25_capturing/)
3. you can use third party monitoring tools
4. You can use profiler. But, it can have some impact due to the way you are setting it up to observer every tsql statement

[Similar question in Stack Exchange DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40960/logging-queries-and-other-t-sql#40963)